# A way to drop all rows with duplicate entries and keep the first and last entry?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

The data contains time stamps for a unique item going through various processes of production. There are about 2k serial numbers and I only want the first and last time it is registered in the data. Is there a way?

```
data[' Cycle Time'] = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(data[' Cycle Time'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))

data = data.drop_duplicates(axis=0, keep="first", keep="last")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([
    df['X'].drop_duplicates(keep='first'),
    df['X'].drop_duplicates(keep='last'),
])
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.